# ESP32 micro-ROS: "Failed status on line 87: 1. Aborting."

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my first time using micro-ROS.

I am following [this tutorial](https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/) with the difference that the connection that I am setting up is through UDP rather than Serial.

After having flashed the given ping_pong app into the ESP and checked that it has successfully connected to my wifi, I launch a micro-ROS agent.

However, I cannot see the new */microROS/ping* and */microROS/pong* topics, so with `ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh monitor` I realize that the following error occurs:

```
Failed status on line 87: 1. Aborting.
```

I tried to search online the possible cause, but didn't find anything solving the problem.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387035/esp32-micro-ros:-%22failed-status-on-line-87:-1.-aborting.%22/) by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) on 2021-09-21**:
I don't know if that "line 87" refers to the file *app.c* of the ping_pong app. But if that is the case, I leave you [here](https://github.com/micro-ROS/freertos_apps/blob/10a478bba2c83561036126ca85ab789273856991/apps/ping_pong/app.c#L87) the line it would be referring to.

**Comment by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) on 2021-09-21**:
I see someone else had the [same problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/378016/failed-status-in-rclc_support_init/), and solved changing the IP address in the configuration.

However, if we're talking about the step `ros2 run micro_ros_setup configure_firmware.sh ping_pong -t udp -i <IP_ADDRESS> -p 8888` I am already using the IP address of my machine (not the one of the ESP32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[SOLUTION]

The problem was that my firewall blocked the UDP connection between the ESP32 and the micro-ROS agent.

It was sufficient to allow such connection in the firewall rules, and everything went fine.

---

Originally posted by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) with karma: 18 on 2021-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0